# Timpani alternative in the band room

Tags: percussion, band, timpani

I’m looking for a cheaper alternative to the timpani, that may be used in a middle school band.

Any Ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've seen Rototoms used for this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rototom

Comment: Electronic drums can be set up to sound like timps, with a small amp. The feel won't be the same, but for rehearsals, they'd suffice - and be cheaper and take up less room!

Comment: Tympani have pitches.  There's not a lot of alternative drums (contained airspace with membrane surface) that will sound like them.

Answer (score 2):

A midi drum kit should do the trick. You'll need a proper VST too though.

Answer (score 0):

One option is a keyboard with timpani sounds. Roland, for example, has some options that sound great and will even play a roll for a held key (not sure about glissandos with the pitch wheel).  You could also trigger the keyboard with a drum pad via midi to preserve more of the visual aspect of drumming for a performance if you want.

Electronic drums could possibly work too, but since timpani are tonal, the interface for finding pitches on a keyboard will be less problematic and error prone.

Comment: A friend of mine has a device that looks like a xylophone that can be programmed with sounds, among which are timpani.  It's pricey though, might be out of reach for a middle school band budget.  And there's still the issue of the feel, but there's not much that can be done about that.